# find user and add user with parse and get an error

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, parse-platform

I want my app to be able to add friend's username and show them in friend list view controller. My view will have username textfield for users to fill in order to search for friends and an add button to add them.
The process is that you type friend's username in the textfield and press add, it will search to see if that user is existing; If exists, the app will automatically add that username and go to friend list view controller where I have to update friend list. I'm currently using **Parse**.                      Here's my code for adding user with parse in **Swift**

```
@IBAction func addUser(sender: AnyObject) {
    var query = PFUser.query()
    var currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()
    query.whereKey("username", equalTo: usernameTextField) 
    query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock{ (objects: PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in 

        if error == nil {
            var friendList = PFUser.currentUser().relationForKey("friends")
            var addFriend = objects
            if addFriend != nil {
                PFRelation.addObject(addFriend)
                println("added")
            }
            PFUser.currentUser().saveInBackgroundWithBlock{
                (succeeded: Bool!, error: NSError!) in

                if error != nil {
                    println("Error")
                }
                else {
                    println("saved")
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

My app shows error `PFObject` is not convertible to `PFRelation`
This is the code that I've found in **Stackoverlow** and tried

```
@IBAction func addUser(sender: AnyObject) {
    var query = PFUser.query()
    var now = PFUser.currentUser()
    query.whereKey("username", equalTo: usernameTextField) // use Breakpoint at this point and ok
    query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock {          // <- use Breakpoint at this point and my app crash
        (object: PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if object == nil {
            NSLog("The getFirstObject request failed.")
            //add alertView here later

        } else {
            // The find succeeded.
            NSLog("Successfully retrieved the object.")
            //This can find username successfully
        }
        var friendsRelation : PFRelation = now.relationForKey("friendsRelation")
        friendsRelation.addObject(object)
    }
}
```

I've tried solutions that I've found in **Stackoverlow** and other sites but I still can't get it to work. I've tried `for user in users` (users is equal to my object) loop but it didn't work. Did I miss some concepts here? If so, how do you write codes to add username and show them in friend list view controller, I don't know what to do now. I would greatly appreciate any helps you can give me and let me know if you need any additional information (By the way my app will not link to Facebook at anyway).
Thank you!

Comment: What line does that error get generated on?

Comment: For you first portion of code, it will have compiler error because `PFUser.currentUser()` returns optional. Are you sure you understand the codes?

Comment: I don't understand much about this code and my error generated on this line 'PFRelation.addObject(addFriend)' could you explain more about what I do wrong?. Thanks